# Rounding with awk -0.0

Tags: csv, awk, data-processing

I am using awk to round floating values in a csv file using (in a pipe)

```
awk '{$0=sprintf("%.2f",$1)}1'
```

This works basically fine, but has the problem that it produces both "0.00" and "-0.00" depending on whether the rounded number was just below or just above zero. Is there a way to get rid of the "-" sign on "-0.00"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "0.001" | awk '{$0=sprintf("%.2f",($1<0?-$1:$1))}1'
0.00
$ echo "-0.001" | awk '{$0=sprintf("%.2f",($1<0?-$1:$1))}1'
0.00
```

Comment: This seems to make all my numbers positive (which is not what I want). Only "-0.00" should be changed to "0.00"

Comment: That wasnt clear from your question. Always post a few (5-10) cases of sample input and expected output. Once you update your question if you leave me a comment I'll take another look, I don't want to waste time misunderstanding your requirements a second time.